# Unity Conflict - No valid assets

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Unity Collab with my other team member to develop our game. After integrating the FireBGase Database asset package, I noticed that he had made a change to the project. I then pulled his changes and since then I have a conflict in Unity in my Plugins/Android folder.

Right-Clicking on any of the folders marked red presents me with an option to Resolve Conflicts. Regardless if I click Take theirs or Keep Mine - I am presented with an error stating "There are no valid assets to this operation on". 
There are no files marked as having a conflict, only folders.

[image]

I am using the latest version of Unity 2017.3.1f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have yet been unable to find an answer for this issue.

Removing the Plugins and Androids file from Unity and adding them back in removed the conflicts on those two files - but there was still a conflict on the Assets folder.

In the end, I made a backup of my project and reverted the project to previous version on Collab.

I then add to readd the FireBase assets and copy back my changed code. A little bit of effort but it resolved the issue.